# How to use Canopy with Browserstack

Tags: f#, canopy-web-testing

I have been user the f# test library Canopy and it works great. But I can't figure out how to have it target browsers on browser stack. I did find this but so it is/was possible.

[twitter.com/bryan_hunter/status/423352533877153792](http://twitter.com/bryan_hunter/status/423352533877153792)

Answer (score 5):

```
//Import the required libraries
open canopy
open runner
open System
open OpenQA.Selenium
open OpenQA.Selenium.Remote

//Set the BrowserStack specific capabilities 
let capability = new DesiredCapabilities()
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "username")
capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "accesskey")
capability.SetCapability("os", "Windows")
capability.SetCapability("os_version", "7")
capability.SetCapability("browser", "Chrome")
capability.SetCapability("browser_version", "46.0")

//Setup Remote WebDriver to run on BrowserStack
let remote = Remote("http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub/", capability)

//Start the browser 
start remote

//Put your tests here

//Run all tests
run()

//close the driver
quit()
```